# How can I add space between Posted on January 13, 2016 and January 13, 2016 by admin?

Tags: wordpress

I wan to make space between "Posted on January 13, 2016January 13, 2016 by admin" .How can I add space between Posted on January 13, 2016 and January 13, 2016 by admin?

Comment: my post link is:http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/local-advertising-that-doesnt-work/

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: where to add this code?

Comment: Add it to your theme's style.css

Comment: why it shows "January 13, 2016" two times?

Comment: First date is when the post was published and the latter one is the date when the post was last updated. If you want to hide the second one then add this css in your style.css: `.posted-on .updated {display:none;}` Better practice would be to remove the second date from your theme's .php files. But I don't think you have any knowledge about that

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to add the space:

```
.posted-on .published {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

P.S. Please at least try something before posting a question on SO. Thanks